# Python scraping with bs4 brings wrong output

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

I'm trying to scrape from this html code the src.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


soup = BeautifulSoup(data.text, 'html.parser')
title = soup.find_all(attrs={'class': 'main-image-class'})[0].get('src')
```

But the output is data:image/gif;base64. How do I get the src link?

The website code:

```
<img src="https://en.aw-lab.com/dw/image/v2/BCLG_PRD/on/demandware.static/-/Sites-awlab-master-catalog/default/dwbf1e5118/images/bata/large-sport-shoe-8047751-0.jpg?sw=843" alt="NIKE AIR JORDAN 1 MID, GREEN" title="NIKE AIR JORDAN 1 MID, GREEN" class="main-image-class" srcset="https://en.aw-lab.com/dw/image/v2/BCLG_PRD/on/demandware.static/-/Sites-awlab-master-catalog/default/dwbf1e5118/images/bata/large-sport-shoe-8047751-0.jpg?sw=710 710w, https://en.aw-lab.com/dw/image/v2/BCLG_PRD/on/demandware.static/-/Sites-awlab-master-catalog/default/dwbf1e5118/images/bata/large-sport-shoe-8047751-0.jpg?sw=1420 710w, https://en.aw-lab.com/dw/image/v2/BCLG_PRD/on/demandware.static/-/Sites-awlab-master-catalog/default/dwbf1e5118/images/bata/large-sport-shoe-8047751-0.jpg?sw=556 556w, https://en.aw-lab.com/dw/image/v2/BCLG_PRD/on/demandware.static/-/Sites-awlab-master-catalog/default/dwbf1e5118/images/bata/large-sport-shoe-8047751-0.jpg?sw=1112 556w, https://en.aw-lab.com/dw/image/v2/BCLG_PRD/on/demandware.static/-/Sites-awlab-master-catalog/default/dwbf1e5118/images/bata/large-sport-shoe-8047751-0.jpg?sw=843 843w, https://en.aw-lab.com/dw/image/v2/BCLG_PRD/on/demandware.static/-/Sites-awlab-master-catalog/default/dwbf1e5118/images/bata/large-sport-shoe-8047751-0.jpg?sw=1686 843w" sizes="(max-width: 767px) 710px, (max-width: 1199px) and (min-width: 768px) 556px, (min-width: 1200px) 843px">
```

Comment: Your code works for me with the supplied HTML.

Comment: There must be another element with that same class.

Comment: I checked too and works as expected, giving output as url.

Comment: If I scrape the whole html code with bs4 I get this src link "data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAP///wAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==".

Comment: What is the length of the collection returned from `soup.find_all(attrs={'class': 'main-image-class'})`?